# Why do most PyQt tutorials create classes from widgets?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, conventions

TLDR why do people create classes (Window for example) when its only going to be used once?

Some examples:
[RealPython, the first code block](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-layout/#using-general-purpose-layout-managers)
[PythonBasics, first code block](https://pythonbasics.org/pyqt-buttons/)
[PythonPyQt, first code block](https://pythonpyqt.com/pyqt-grid-layout/)

Why can't they put the code in the main program (using the RealPython example):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Qwidget.setWindowTitle("QHBoxLayout Example")
    window.show()
    # Create a QHBoxLayout instance
    layout = QHBoxLayout()
    # Add widgets to the layout
    layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Left-Most"))
    layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Center"), 1)
    layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Right-Most"), 2)
    # Set the layout on the application's window
    window.setLayout(layout)
    print(window.children())
    sys.exit(app._exec())
```

Instead of

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("QHBoxLayout Example")
        # Create a QHBoxLayout instance
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        # Add widgets to the layout
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Left-Most"))
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Center"), 1)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Right-Most"), 2)
        # Set the layout on the application's window
        self.setLayout(layout)
        print(self.children())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but don't put code into the `__name__ == "__main__"` block directly, that will put all the local variables into the global scope. [Click for more details.](https://youtu.be/g_wlZ9IhbTs)

Comment: I don't use Qt a lot but I think this is done just to organize code.

Comment: for people who want to write bigger projects. If you just have a small script, then dont need to.

Comment: In PyQt, custom signals and slots must be defined in a subclass, and most Qt classes have virtual and protected methods that must be reimplemented in a sublass in order to change the default behaviour. In Python, this can also be achieved by monkey-patching, but the resulting code can often become ugly and difficult to read/debug. Also, that approach isn't possible in C++, and since many PyQt tutorials/examples are derived from the Qt documentation, it would require substantial re-writing to adapt them. Like it or not, subclassing is an essential part of Qt, so it's best to go with the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a big program it's really hard to put all of them in the main program and deal with all the widgets created in a single file.

with separate classes you have access to the QWidget, and you can also inherit additionally some QDesigner created GUIs.

```
from Codebase.GUI.MyMainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

class ExampleDesignerMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow)
    def __init__(self)
        super(ExampleDesignerMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # do something
```

and then you can have access to everything and instantiate in the "main program" whenever you want.